# Enabling TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, encryption

I am trying to connect to a host using Java. The host when connected from the browser shows that it is using cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. When I run the code in Java to connect to the same host, the program is not sending the same cipher suite and so I get a handshake error.

> Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

After reading over the internet I thought the cause could be due to different ciphers. So I tried to enable the same cipher in my Java program using:

```
String pickedCipher[] ={"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"}; 
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(pickedCipher);
```

This give me error:

> Cannot support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently
>   installed providers

I searched over internet and most found that I need to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. Extrat the JAR's in .\jre\lib\security.
I did the same but still I am not able to enable the needed cipher suite and keep getting the unsupported providers error.

I have searched and tried whatever is suggested over the internet but could not make the connection. Can anyone help me.

Code I am trying:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(); 
SSLSocket socket=null;
socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("147.249.141.13", 443);
enCiphersuite=socket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enCiphersuite);
socket.startHandshake();
```

Comment: You must have done it wrong. If you're using a JRE inside a JDK you Have to install it there as well.

Comment: I have installed the JAR's in both the locations:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security and 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security

Comment: I removed all the Java version from the system and cleaned all the temp files. Installed Java and JCE. Worked like charm! Thanks!